# How to detect partitions (clusters) of sparse data in linear time, and (hopefully) sublinear space?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, partitioning, intervals, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have *m* integers from *n* disjoint integer intervals, which are in some sense "far" apart.
*n* is **not** known beforehand, but it is known to be small (see assumptions below).

For example, for *n* = 3, I might have been given randomly distributed integers from the intervals 105-2400, 58030-571290, 1000000-1000100.

Finding the minimum (105) and maximum (1000100) is clearly trivial.
But is there any way to efficiently (in O(*m*) time and hopefully o(*m*) space) find the intervals' boundary points, so that I can quickly partition the data for separate processing?

If there is no efficient way to do this exactly, is there an efficient way to *approximate* the partitions, to within a small constant factor (like 2)?
(For example, 4000 would be an acceptable approximation of the upper bound of the smaller interval, and 30000 would be an acceptable approximation of the lower bound of the middle interval.)

Assumptions:

1. Everything is nonnegative
2. *n* is very small (say, < 10)
3. The max value is comparatively large (say, on the order of 2<sup>26</sup>)
4. The intervals are dense (i.e. there exists an integer in the array for most values inside that interval)
5. Two clusters are far apart if their closest boundaries are at least a constant factor *c* apart.
   (**Edit:** It makes sense for *c* to be relative to the *cluster size* rather than relative to the bound. So a cluster of 1 element at 1000000 should **not** be approximated as originating from the interval 500000-2000000.)
6. The integers are **not** sorted, and this is crucial. In fact sorting them in O(m) time is impossible without radix sort, but radix sort could have O(max value) complexity, and there is no guarantee the max value is anywhere close to *m*.

Again, speed is the most important factor here; inaccuracy is tolerated as long as it's within a reasonable factor.

Comment: By 4., you mean "the integers in an interval are dense", and not "the intervals are dense over the set of all integers", right?

Comment: Your condition 5 is also unclear to me.  Are the clusters meant to be further apart than the size of any one cluster?  For that problem, I think I can come up with an algorithm that is O(m) time and constant space.  But in your example, most of the space is taken up by a cluster from 1 million to 20 million, which is much larger than any of the distances between the clusters?

Comment: @user2580516: Yes for 4. For 5, yes, clusters might indeed be very far apart -- that's the entire point of that bullet. So you might have [100, 101, 102, 200, 201, 202, 300, 301, 302, ...]. The example was just an example for illustration of the problem, obviously it doesn't cover every single detail... that's why the rest of the question is there. I changed the example though, hopefully it'll help.

Comment: @Mehrdad Your second interval is 513260 long, so the "very far apart" condition is not met here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I was wrong when I  posted the question -- the answer does seem to be radix sort.

The number of buckets is arbitrary, it doesn't have to correlate with the sizes of the intervals.
It might even be 2, if I go bit-by-bit.

Thus radix sort could help me sort the data in O(m log(max value)) ≈ O(m) time (since log(max value) is essentially a constant factor of 26 according to the assumptions), at which point the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: You even could use an 8 MiB bitmap.

Answer (score 4):

I say move to a logarithmic scale of factor *c* to search for the intervals, since you know them being at least *c* factor apart. Then, make an array of counters, each counter counts numbers in intervals `(0.5X .. 0.5X+0.5)` logarithmic scale, where `X` is the index of selected counter.

Say, *c* is 2, and you know the maximum upper bound of 2<sup>26</sup>, so you create 52 counters, then calculate `floor(2*log<sub>2</sub>i)` where `i` is the current integer, and increment that counter. After you parse all of *m* integers, walk through that array, and each sequence of zeroes in there will mean that the corresponding logarithmic interval is empty.

So the output of this will be the sequence of occupied intervals, logarithmically aligned to halves of power of *c*, aka 128, 181, 256, 363, 512 etc. This satisfies your requirements on precision for intervals' boundaries.

Update: You can also store lowest and highest number out of those that hit the interval. Once you do, the intervals' boundaries are calculated as follows:

1. Find the first nonzero counter from current position in the counters array. Take its lowest number as lower bound.
2. Progress through the counters array until you find a zero in the counter or hit the array's end. Take the last nonzero counter's highest number. This will be your upper bound for the current interval.
3. Proceed until full traversal of the array.
4. Return the set of intervals found. The boundaries will be strict.

An example: (abstract language code)

```
counters=[];
lowest=[];
highest=[];
for (i=0;i<m;i++) { 
    x=getNextInteger();
    n=Math.floor(2.0*logByBase(c,x));
    counters[n]++;
    if (counters[n]==1) {
        lowest[n]=x;
        highest[n]=x;
    } else {
        if (lowest[n]>x) lowest[n]=x;
        if (highest[n]<x) highest[n]=x;
    }
}
zeroflag=true; /// are we in mode of finding a zero or a nonzero
intervals=[];
currentLow=0;
currentHigh=0;
for (i=0;i<counters.length;i++) {
    if (zeroflag) {
        // we search for nonzero
        if (counters[i]>0) {
            currentLow=lowest[i]; // there's a value
            zeroflag=false;
        } // else skip
    } else {
        if (counters[i]==0) {
            currentHigh=highest[i-1]; // previous was nonzero, get its highest
            intervals.push([currentLow,currentHigh]); // store interval
            zeroflag=true;
    }
}
if (!zeroflag) { // unfinished interval 
    currentHigh=highest[counters.length-1];
    intervals.push([currentLow,currentHigh]); // store last interval
}
```

Comment: Oh wait actually I think I missed something important in my question -- if the interval is 1000-1001, then I really *don't* want to approximate it as 500-2000... that's grossly inefficient. I think I need it to be within a constant factor of the interval size, not necessarily a constant factor of the interval bounds.

Comment: Hmm, if I understand this correctly I think this doesn't quite work -- for example, say I have the numbers [128, 129, 254, 255]. If they all fall into the same bucket (say, because we're grouping by powers of 2) then the bucket will be approximated as 128-255, which is grossly inefficient since there are clearly 2 intervals of size 2, but the two intervals are 124 apart... right?

Comment: Your example is far from the sample you gave in you OP. Your set is not dense and the values are not (logarithmically) far apart. If you want to separate into at least N groups, you will have to adapt the granularity of the logarithmic search (increase the number of steps until you find between N and 2N groups).

Comment: @Merhdad 129*2 = 258, this is more than 254 for second interval, that's why this won't work. To make it work, reduce *c* to say 1.9, as 129*1.9 = 245.1, which is less than 254.

Comment: @kuroineko: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying. How are the intervals *not* dense? There are clearly two dense intervals here -- 128-129 and 254-255 -- but we're approximating that as 128-255, which is a very poor approximation. Is this different from what I said before?

Comment: @Vesper: Ah but read what I'd written again. *c* should be multiplied by the **size** of the interval, *not* by its boundary. So in this case we'd be multiplying *c* by 129 - 128 + 1 = 2, i.e. our approximation of the upper bound of the lower interval should be no more than 129 + c * 2

Comment: You've said "a factor of *c* apart", a factor is a multiplication. The common sense says that "a factor of *c* apart" means that lower bound of next interval is at least *c* times bigger than upper bound of previous interval. Now you say something about the width of those intervals, which is highly indetermined. I don't understand, let's say we have an array of [1000000, 1000100, 1000103]. Is this 3 intervals or 2, or one?

Comment: @Mehrad I meant basically the same as Vesper just explained. The initial assumption was to have any lower bound distant of the next upper bound by a factor of two, but you can reduce this separation factor to have a finer grain if you whish. As I said, you can even use an adaptative search based on a min and max value of expected groups.

Comment: @Vesper: [In my very first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953427/how-to-detect-partitions-clusters-of-sparse-data-in-linear-time-and-hopefull?noredirect=1#comment33260480_21953569) I said *"I need it to be within a constant factor of the interval **size**"*, right? With the array you gave me, it's 3 intervals for c <= 2, 2 intervals for 3 <= c <= 99, and 1 interval for 100 <= c.

Comment: Actually it seems like my analysis regarding radix sort was wrong, I could indeed just do radix sort with a small number of buckets. It would take O(m) time... so I think I found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at **aproximate median finding**.

These methods can often be generalized to finding arbitrary quantiles with a reasonable precision; and quantiles are good for distributing your work load.

Here's my take, using two passes over the data set.

1. sample 10000 objects from your data set.
2. Solve your problem for the sample objects.
3. Re-scan your data set, assigning each object to the nearest interval from your sample, and tracking the minimum and maximum of *each interval*.

If your gaps are prominent enough, they should still be visible in the sample. The second pass is only to refine the interval boundaries.

Comment: I think this is a different problem -- but I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Split the total range into buckets.  The bucket boundaries `X_i` should be spaced in an appropriate way, like e.g. linearly `X_i=16*i`.  Other options would be quadratic spacing like `X_i=4*i*i` or logarithmic `X_i=2^(i/16)`, here the total number of buckets would be smaller but finding the right bucket for a given number would be more effort.  Each bucket is empty or non-empty, so one bit would be sufficient.
You iterate over the set of numbers, and for each number you mark its bucket as non-empty.  Then the gaps between your intervals are represented by series of empty buckets.  So now you find all sufficiently  long series of empty buckets, and you have the interval gaps.  The accuracy of the interval boundary will be determined by the bucket size, so assuming a bucket size of 16 you interval border is off by at most 15.  If the max number is 2<sup>26</sup> and buckets are size 16 and you use one bit for each bucket you need 2<sup>19</sup> byte, or 512kB of memory.